# Mui Button color onClick turning all tabs different color rather than active tab

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a footer with 5 links, which I am using a Mui Button for with component={Link} to transform into links.
The buttons are all black, I have a hover state that changes the button to green when hovered over, but I want to keep the button color green if it has been clicked.
At the moment the onClick is changing all the buttons to green not just the active one.

I have tried several different solutions-all result in same issue. Thank you so much to anyone that can help!

solution fail #1:

```
  const styles = {
    footerLogo: {
     width: '300px',
     height: '57px',
     align: 'center'
    },
    navLink: {
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: 'black',
      "&:hover":{
        color:'green'
      }
    },
    active: {
      color: 'green'
    }
  };

  const navButtons = [
    {
      button: "Services",
      link: "/services",
    },
    {
      button: "Featured Work",
      link: "/work",
    },
    {
      button: "About",
      link: "/about",
    },
    {
      button: "Contact",
      link: "/contact",
    },
  ];

  
  const location = window.location.pathname;

  const currentTab = location === navButtons[0].link ? styles.active : styles.navLink


 
 <Box
       display='flex'
       justifyContent='space-around'
       marginTop='50px'
      >
        {navButtons.map(({button, link, index}) => (
          <Button
              key={index}
              to={link}
              component={Link}
              sx={currentTab}
             
          >
            {button}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

solution fail #2:

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  

const handleClick = () => {
    setIsClicked(true)
  }

 <Box
       display='flex'
       justifyContent='space-around'
       marginTop='50px'
      >
        {navButtons.map(({button, link, index}) => (
          <Button
              key={index}
              to={link}
              component={Link}
              onClick={handleClick}
              sx={{
                color : isClicked ? "green" : "black",
                 ":hover":{
                   color:'green'
                 }
               }}
          >
            {button}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

Comment: this won't work because you need to store a index of the selected link rather true false state. because it will be true for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [isClickedIndex, setIsClickedIndex] = useState(false);
  

const handleClick = (index) => {
    setIsClickedIndex(index)
  }

 <Box
       display='flex'
       justifyContent='space-around'
       marginTop='50px'
      >
        {navButtons.map(({button, link, index}) => (
          <Button
              key={index}
              to={link}
              component={Link}
              onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}
              sx={{
                color : isClickedIndex === index ? "green" : "black",
                 ":hover":{
                   color:'green'
                 }
               }}
          >
            {button}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

Comment: try this and see if it's working?

Answer (score 0):

In first solution, you are always comparing **location** with first navbutton link i.e **navButtons[0].link**

As for you second solution
isClicked state is for the component and not for individual button. So rather than having one state for isClicked you can keep isClicked in your navBtn array.